# What type of format is this in ERLANG. Doesnt look like JSON?

Tags: erlang, mqtt, erlang-shell

I just dumped this variable using `file:write`:

```
file:write_file("/tmp/foo.txt", io_lib:fwrite("~p.\n", [Message])),
```

This is part of plugin code in emqtt.
I want to parse this contents and get the part sdfjksdf in a message variable and home/garden/fountain in a variable called topic. How to do this. I dont know erlang.

```
{mqtt_message,<<0,5,101,163,106,150,123,212,110,126,0,0,76,244,0,3>>,
              undefined,
              {<<"1852fadb884d46c7a349f6a974846ce1">>,undefined},
              <<"home/garden/fountain">>,0,[],false,false,false,[],
              <<"sdfjksdf">>,
              {1519,127425,874902}}
```

This is the function i am having trouble with

```
on_message_publish(Message, _Env) ->
    io:format("publish ~s~n", [emqttd_message:format(Message)]),
    file:write_file("/tmp/foo.txt", io_lib:fwrite("~p.\n", [Message])),
    inets:start(),
    Method = post,
    URL = "http://xyz.in/api/v2/mysql/_table/device",
    Header = [{"Api-Key", "1234"}],
    Type = "application/json",
    Body = "{\"resource\":[{\"deviceid\":\"" ++ "msg" ++ "\"}]}",
    HTTPOptions = [],
    Options = [],
    R = httpc:request(Method, {URL, Header, Type, Body}, HTTPOptions, Options),
    {ok, Message}.
```

In the above code, i have to pass the string "sdfjksdf" from the Message object and send in place of "msg" string. 
I tried ++ element(12,Message) ++ But it doesnt work.

Then I tried ++ binary_to_list(element(12,Message)) ++ this also doesnt work.

How do i pass the string "sdfjksdf" from Message object passed into the function as argument in the JSON string by concatenation.

Comment: you shouldn't add to this question all your questions about Erlang. Don't overload it. Make new or (even better) start search answer for it by own.

Answer (score 3):

That's a tuple in erlang.  See: http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html.  Here's the tuple organized with each element on a separate line:

```
{
    mqtt_message,
    <<0,5,101,163,106,150,123,212,110,126,0,0,76,244,0,3>>,
    undefined,
    {<<"1852fadb884d46c7a349f6a974846ce1">>,undefined},
    <<"home/garden/fountain">>,
    0,
    [],
    false,
    false,
    false,
    [],
    <<"sdfjksdf">>,
    {1519,127425,874902}
}
```

The index of the first element in a tuple is 1. So you can do something like this:

```
8> Data = f:get_data().
{mqtt_message,<<0,5,101,163,106,150,123,212,110,126,0,0,
                76,244,0,3>>,
              undefined,
              {<<"1852fadb884d46c7a349f6a974846ce1">>,undefined},
              <<"home/garden/fountain">>,0,[],false,false,false,[],
              <<"sdfjksdf">>,
              {1519,127425,874902}}

9> Message = element(12, Data).
<<"sdfjksdf">>

10> Topic = element(5, Data).
<<"home/garden/fountain">>
```

**Response to comment:**

> Also could you please tell what is the meaning of <<>> symbol in above
>   tuple

If you had searched through the page at the link I posted above, which lists all the erlang data types, you would have discovered that a element like this:

```
<<"sdfjksdf">>
```

is called a *binary*.  Binaries are like strings, but for binaries erlang provides a syntax that allows you to slice a binary into chunks of bits of any size you desire.  That is very useful for reading strings sent over a network when the first 4 bits may represent the length of the entire message, the next 12 bits represent some info, the next 3 bits represent some other info, etc.

But because binaries are also more efficient than strings, even if you don't need to slice a string up into its constituent bits, you can convert strings to binaries and pass them around.  All the I/O facilities in erlang can handle binaries more efficiently than strings.

But, if for some reason you need the binary as a string, you can convert the binary to a string using the function `binary_to_list()`.  In erlang, a string is really a *list* which contains integer character codes:

```
9> [97,98,99].
"abc"
```

...hence the name binary_to_list.

Here's an example that converts a binary to a string:

```
7> TopicBin = <<"home/garden/fountain">>.
<<"home/garden/fountain">>

8> TopicStr = binary_to_list(TopicBin).
"home/garden/fountain"
9>
```

**Response to edit:**

> I tried `++ element(12,Message) ++` But it doesnt work.

We already established that the return value of `element(12, Message`) was a binary, but you should check to make sure:

```
X = element(12, Message),
io:format("What is this: ~w~n", [X])
```

Next, the `++` operator is a shortcut for [string:concat()](https://erldocs.com/19.0/stdlib/string.html?i=0&search=string:concat#concat/2) which requires string arguments, so you can't use `++` with binaries.

> Then I tried `++ binary_to_list(element(12,Message)) ++` this also doesnt work.

This works:

```
2> Msg = "sdfjksdf".
"sdfjksdf"

3> Result = "hello " ++ Msg ++ " world".
"hello sdfjksdf world"
```

And previously, we discussed  how to convert a binary to a string(list).  So, you can do this:

```
5> Bin = <<"sdfjksdf">>.
<<"sdfjksdf">>

6> Msg = binary_to_list(Bin).   
"sdfjksdf"

7> "hello " ++ Msg ++ " world".
```

And, the last line is equivalent to:

```
8> "hello " ++ binary_to_list(Bin) ++ " world".
"hello sdfjksdf world"
```

Here it is inside your function:

```
-module(f).
-compile(export_all).

get_message() ->
{
    mqtt_message,
    <<0,5,101,163,106,150,123,212,110,126,0,0,76,244,0,3>>,
    undefined,
    {<<"1852fadb884d46c7a349f6a974846ce1">>,undefined},
    <<"home/garden/fountain">>,
    0,
    [],
    false,
    false,
    false,
    [],
    <<"sdfjksdf">>,
    {1519,127425,874902}
}.


on_message_publish(Message, _Env) ->
    %io:format("publish ~s~n", [emqttd_message:format(Message)]),
    %file:write_file("/tmp/foo.txt", io_lib:fwrite("~p.\n", [Message])),
    %inets:start(),
    DeviceIdBin = element(12, Message),
    DeviceIdStr = binary_to_list(DeviceIdBin),

    Method = post,
    URL = "http://xyz.in/api/v2/mysql/_table/device",
    Header = [{"Api-Key", "1234"}],
    Type = "application/json",
    Body = "{\"resource\":[{\"deviceid\":\"" ++ DeviceIdStr ++ "\"}]}",
    io:format("Body=~s~n", [Body]),
    %HTTPOptions = [],
    %Options = [],
    %R = httpc:request(Method, {URL, Header, Type, Body}, HTTPOptions, Options),
    {ok, Message}.


go() ->
    Message = get_message(),
    on_message_publish(Message, "hello").
```

In the erlang shell:

```
5> c(f).  
f.erl:29: Warning: variable 'Method' is unused
f.erl:30: Warning: variable 'URL' is unused
f.erl:31: Warning: variable 'Header' is unused
f.erl:32: Warning: variable 'Type' is unused
{ok,f}

6> f:go().
Body={"resource":[{"deviceid":"sdfjksdf"}]}
{ok,{mqtt_message,<<0,5,101,163,106,150,123,212,110,126,0,
                    0,76,244,0,3>>,
                  undefined,
                  {<<"1852fadb884d46c7a349f6a974846ce1">>,undefined},
                  <<"home/garden/fountain">>,0,[],false,false,false,[],
                  <<"sdfjksdf">>,
                  {1519,127425,874902}}}
7>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. This explains it.
Also could you please tell what is the meaning of <<>> symbol in above tuple. 
Now this was how the message looked when i wrote it to file to see how the object structure looks like. 
Without writing to file i guess i can just access it like Topic = element(5,Message)
I will try this and update.

Comment: @RaviPujar, See my response at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I understand that it is binary string now. 
I have updated my question with actual problem i am facing. 
Could you please guide on how to do this.

Comment: @RaviPujar, See my response at the bottom of my post.

Comment: Awesome :)
It worked. 
Just added
DeviceIdBin = element(12, Message),
DeviceIdStr = binary_to_list(DeviceIdBin),
and then 
++ DeviceIdStr ++

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

The type is called a `tuple` and is an Erlang data type. You can typically consider it a fixed-length array. Erlang tuples are 1-indexed. There are several ways to extract data from a tuple. If you know the size of the tuple, for example:

```
{_,_,_,_,Message,_,_,_,_,_,_,Topic,_} = {mqtt_message,<<0,5,101,163,106,150,123,212,110,126,0,0,76,244,0,3>>,
              undefined,
              {<<"1852fadb884d46c7a349f6a974846ce1">>,undefined},
              <<"home/garden/fountain">>,0,[],false,false,false,[],
              <<"sdfjksdf">>,
              {1519,127425,874902}}.
```

This will bind your desired data to the Message and Topic variables respectively. Or use the built in function `element`:

```
element(5, {mqtt_message,<<0,5,101,163,106,150,123,212,110,126,0,0,76,244,0,3>>,
              undefined,
              {<<"1852fadb884d46c7a349f6a974846ce1">>,undefined},
              <<"home/garden/fountain">>,0,[],false,false,false,[],
              <<"sdfjksdf">>,
              {1519,127425,874902}})
```

or:

```
element(12, {mqtt_message,<<0,5,101,163,106,150,123,212,110,126,0,0,76,244,0,3>>,
              undefined,
              {<<"1852fadb884d46c7a349f6a974846ce1">>,undefined},
              <<"home/garden/fountain">>,0,[],false,false,false,[],
              <<"sdfjksdf">>,
              {1519,127425,874902}})
```

I hope this answers your question, cheers!

EDIT:
The `<<>>` is an Erlang binary, which is a pretty large subject. You can read about the data type and about built in binary operations [here](http://erlang.org/doc/man/binary.html).

EDIT2:
I am not entirely sure what you mean by your last edit to the original post. However If you want to simply extract the binary `<<"sdfjksdf">>` and append it to an existing string:

```
42> Msg = binary:bin_to_list(element(12,Message)).
"sdfjksdf"
43> "test: " ++ Msg.
"test: sdfjksdf"
```

You need to figure out the correct way to append it into the JSON body using that syntax. Keep in mind that the `++` operation is ineffective for large lists.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. I understand now. 
Also could you please tell what is the meaning of <<>> symbol in above tuple.

Comment: <<>> is empty Erlang binary data type

Comment: This can has some integers or characters like above.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now. 
I have updated my question with actual problem i am facing. 
Could you please guide on how to do this.
I am unable to get the string out for passing to HTTP request.

Comment: I updated my answer to try to help you further, please check it out.

Comment: Thank you . I will try it. 
I want to extract it, correct.

Comment: Awesome :)
It worked. 
Just added
DeviceIdBin = element(12, Message),
DeviceIdStr = binary_to_list(DeviceIdBin),
and then 
++ DeviceIdStr ++

Thank you very much :)